# How to get the number of files from request.FILES.getlist('image')

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

and I'm trying to upload files in the app that I'm making.
I have an input field (ImageField) that accepts multiple images to be uploaded once submitted.
I do this via ajax, and so I want to return some sort of json object that
has total count of images being tried to upload and number of images being actually uploaded.

```
def post_update(request):
    save_status = {'update_save': False, 'image_count': 0, 'image_save': 0}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        update = UpdateForm(request.POST)
        if update.is_valid():
            event = Event.objects.get(pk=request.POST['event_id'])
            update_form = update.save(False)
            update_form.update_by = request.user
            update_form.event = event
            update_form.save()
            save_status['update_save'] = True

            images = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            files = request.FILES.getlist('image_path')
            save_status['image_count'] = request.FILES.count
            if images.is_valid():
                for f in files:
                    photo = Image( image_path=f, update_ref=update_form, image_title=images.cleaned_data.get('image_title'))
                    photo.save()
                    save_status['image_save'] += 1
```

I tried ***request.FILES.count*** and ***request.FILES.length*** in trying to get the count, but to no avail and keeps having an error. My question is basically how can i get the number of files in the request.FILES?

Comment: `files = len(request.FILES.getlist('image_path'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the *length* of the number of images, so:

```
num_files = len(request.FILES.getlist('image_path'))
```

That being said, I would advice to make use of the *form* instead, so use `images.cleaned_data['image_path']`, since these are the items that the form has *cleaned*.

Comment: So you mean, files = images.cleaned_data['image_path'] and num_files = len(images.cleaned_data['image_path']) ?

Comment: @Jcm: or simply `len(files)`.

Comment: it gets an error 'ImageForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'. did you mean `images.cleaned_data.get('image_path')`

Comment: @Jmc: you do this *after* calling `.is_valid()`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data